# How do I form a setting name from a passed parameter?

Tags: c#, parameters, settings, parameter-passing, settings.settings

Say I have a function which recieves a parameter of a string, such as "01" through to "10".

I want to then return the value for one of ym user settings in settings.settings, which have names "Name01", "Name02"... "Name10".

How would I do that?

something similar to:

```
return (Properties.Settings.Default.Name + str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Properties.Settings.Default["Name" + str]
```

Comment: Hmm, one more thing sorry... Would I be able to bind easily to this? I don't fancy having the ten properties in totaljsut to bind... (in reality, I have 25 of these, 4 times over so 100 in total...)

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, are you talking about WPF binding or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I am yes. So, I have a property that gets and sets the setting... but the property can be called "Name" and can decide whether you want Name01 through Name10... Is that doable?

Comment: Yes, you can bind like a property {Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                               Path=["Name01"]} ... don't forgot to add namespace xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:TestSettings.Properties" ...